# Single sign-on for the ASP.Net Core 2.2 base restful service

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-2.2

I have created the Asp.net-core Web API Restful service. Whenever run the application from Visual Studio, the Edge and Chrome browsers are prompting me to login, even though Windows authentication only enabled.

IIS Express and IIS on my local, configured the Windows Authentication. Disabled all other authentications. Added all the windows authentication configurations in the application setting (.json) file. No use.

When I run the application, it should not prompt to enter the login. App should work with my windows authentication.